# Django: Updating foreign_keys

Tags: django, foreign-keys, models

in my project flow I first create a database entry in Orders. At this point, the foreign_key transaction_profile stays empty. At a later point in my checkout_page view, the transaction_profile get's created.

After transaction_profile.save() happened I want to connect the newly created Transaction_Profile with the Order model entry where Order.objects.filter(order_id=request.session['order_id']).

I am really struggling right now to get this done. Anyone here how can help me finding the right track?

checkout > views.py

```
def checkout_page(request):

    if request.POST:
        transaction_profile = TransactionProfileModelForm(request.POST)
        if transaction_profile.is_valid():
            transaction_profile.save()

            o = Order.objects.filter(order_id=request.session['order_id'])
            #if qs.count() == 1:
            o.transaction_profile.add(transaction_profile)

    else:
            transaction_profile = TransactionProfileModelForm()

        context = {
            'transaction_profile': transaction_profile,
        }
[...]
```

transactions > models.py

```
class TransactionProfile(models.Model):
    email           = models.EmailField()
    address_line_1  = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    address_line_2  = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    city            = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    country         = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    state           = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    postal_code     = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    update          = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp       = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

orders > models.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
    order_id                = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    updated                 = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp               = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    transaction_profile     = models.ForeignKey(TransactionProfile, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to save the instance first and assign it to `Order` object:

```
if request.POST:
    transaction_profile = TransactionProfileModelForm(request.POST)
    if transaction_profile.is_valid():
        instance = transaction_profile.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()

        o = Order.objects.get(order_id=request.session['order_id'])
        o.transaction_profile = instance
        o.save()
```